# What can I add to my .btn Bootstrap class so that the puffiness is gone?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to override .btn (and btn-success, btn-info, etc, etc) so that ALL of the background gradient is gone (keep the shadow).

```
.btn{
    //what goes here to remove the background gradient?
    //must work with the other colors
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
.btn {
 background-image:none;
}
```